# Ubuntu 18.04: Power Off pop-up taking around 8-10 seconds to show up

Tags: 18.04

After recent update I noticed that now when I click on the power icon to shutdown/restart the pop-up is taking around 8-10 seconds to show up. This is happening only after clicking it for the first time after login. In the same session on the next subsequent click, the pop-up shows immediately.

I am using Asus Vivobook S14 with Ubuntu 18.04 version. My Kernel version is:

```
4.15.0-23-generic
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using the caffeine extension?

Comment: yes I am and after disabling it, the pop up comes immediately. Any idea why caffeine could be causing this as I have been using this extension for last 2 months or so and this problem started a couple of weeks only..

Comment: It's a known bug in the Caffeine extension, not sure why you didn't experience it before. See the proposed duplicate for alternatives.